# SQL view for searching is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are trying to build a view that provides data in a flattened manner that backs a simple search.

The challenge has been that while we are displaying fields like the name, we are needing to search across fields like address which we don't have displayed, but can still be returned. The address is stored in an address table, and there can be many addresses to each client record.

So I initially thought to do a view that put together the main client record with the various addresses. This resulted in duplicate rows because of the join.

Next, I wrote a query that rolls up these child tables and concatenates them together. This makes it easy to search against and doesn't end up with any duplicates. I put it into a view, but it's pretty slow. I'm preferring to keep it a view because of the nature of the component that is accessing the data, however, I'm not completely opposed to it.

Can this be sped up or am I going about this the wrong way?

Here's the SQL (T-SQL, actually):

```
WITH ClientBase
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Client.ClientID, ClientNames.FirstName, ClientNames.LastName, ClientNames.MiddleName, 
        AddressHistory.Address1 + ' ' + AddressHistory.Address2 AS StreetAddress, 
        AddressHistory.City, ContactInfo.Contact AS Phone
    FROM Client
        INNER JOIN ClientNames ON ClientNames.ClientID = Client.ClientID
        INNER JOIN AddressHistory ON AddressHistory.ClientID = Client.ClientID
        INNER JOIN ContactInfo ON ContactInfo.ClientID = Client.ClientID
)
SELECT DISTINCT vcs.ClientID, vcs.FirstName, vcs.LastName, vcs.MiddleName,
                (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT ';' + ClientBase.StreetAddress AS [text()]
                                FROM ClientBase
                                WHERE ClientBase.ClientID = vcs.ClientID
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS StreetAddress) AS StreetAddress,
                (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT ';' + ClientBase.City AS [text()]
                                FROM ClientBase
                                WHERE ClientBase.ClientID = vcs.ClientID
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS City) AS City,
                (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT ';' + ClientBase.Phone AS [text()]
                                FROM ClientBase
                                WHERE ClientBase.ClientID = vcs.ClientID
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Phone) AS Phone
FROM ClientBase AS vcs
```

Comment: Why do you use DISTINCT clause in view definition when you've implemented inner join between client and addresshistory (where addresshistory can be different, so distinct failed)

Comment: To make searching faster, the important thing to do is add indexes on the fields you want to search, not create a view.

Comment: @Joe, due to the nature of the joins, there ends up being duplicate records. The DISTINCTs weed those out.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not entirely sure that I have a choice when it comes to the view. The search frontend in front of this isn't so much a search as it is a glorified filter and doesn't have any way to execute a more targeted search.

Comment: @kettch:But in field list you put addresshistory fields, so distinct failed.

Comment: @ketch, you can still make it faster with indexes.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks, I'll see about the indexes.

Comment: CTE is just syntax.  That CTE is being evaluated many times.   I would materialize that CTE to a #temp table and put a PK on it if it has one.   And you might also materialize the three XML.

Answer (score 0):

Create indexed view and try to avoid unnecessary distinct clause. 
[Create Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)